# Отловить disabled

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как можно отловить, изменился ли disabled в input?
Желательно без таймеров

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кастомного события насколько я знаю нету.
Возможно самый простой вариант вариант - впилить обработчик в те куски кода которые могу включать-выключать этот инпут

Answer (score 0):

Используйте связывание событий в jquery. С помощью функции bind можно привязать запуск функции к определенному событию.

Comment: Это я и так знаю, какое имя у события?